# Make MatLab run at a constant speed (Even if slower)

Tags: performance, matlab, runtime

I am running a matlab script through a DAQ system to get it create a waveform to control a device. Matlab inherently adds some lag as it runs a script causing the waveform to become offset. I can correct any offset if there is constant lag but the amount of lag for any given loop varys based on my processor performance. The question I need to know is if there is any way that I can write this code to make the matlab lag consistant. Is there anyway to make matlab run at a constant speed regardless of processor performance?

Comment: Windows is not a real time operating system, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling the rate at which the data is output would require real-world time-dependent controls.  If you have a sufficiently simple waveform, then you could control what is output based on calls to your system clock.  But this assumes that your system clock is sufficiently precise.  So, a 1 Hz square wave would be easy to reproduce but a 1 GHz sine wave isn't achievable.  If you can pre-build the waveform, that may get you closer, but it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tic, toc to track the past time? And I condition on toc when it reach your target delay? This can make the lag constant, but the bad thing is that all lags are maximized.